# Jenkins pipeline with kubectl get pods return "unexpected EOF"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to create a Jenkins pipeline with multi-stages, the first stage creates the image, the second stage create new pods from the newly created image and the third stage checks if each pods is alive.

In the third stage one of the commands is:

`result = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i <specific pod name> | wc -l").trim()`

and the value I expect to receive is 1 or 0 but when the command return 0 there is an unexpected EOF error:

/var/jenkins_home/workspace/git-test@tmp/durable-c72ab15c/script.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

after the run failed the location from the error doesn't exist.

How can I get the value I need?

The Stage looks like this:

```
  def isDone = false
  def response = ""
  for (int i = 0; i < 10 && isDone == false; i++) {
    timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') {
      waitUntil {
        response = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "kubectl get pods -o=name --all-namespaces --field-selector status.phase=Running | grep -i $testCaseName | grep . |  awk '{ print (\$1 == \"\") ? \"0\" : \"1\" }'").trim()
        if (response != "") {
          return true
        }
      }
    }
    if (response == '1') {
      sh "echo '$testCaseName pod is running'"
      isDone = true
    } else {
      sh "echo '$testCaseName pod isn't running yet'"
      sleep(time:1,unit:"MINUTES")
    }
```

Comment: I suspect your problem is in your `awk` command as you need to double escape the quotes. You could try moving the command here out into a shell script file and keeping it in your repo. Or just move the whole lot into a shell script then you can run it without iterating though Jenkins

Comment: I suspected that the unexpected EOF came from the `wc` so I have changed the command to: `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i $testCaseName | awk '{ print (\$4 == \"Running\") ? \"yes\" : \"no\" }'` but now I'm starting to think maybe the problem is came from the `returnStdout`

Comment: @RandomGuy17, hey, have you managed it to work?

Comment: Yes, the solution is to wrap the if statement with `try catch` and in the catch section the function needs to do the else case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know for sure the right cause for this problem but I'm assuming that it came from the `readStdout` flag from the Jenkins `sh` command.

The solution for this problem is to wrap with `try catch` the command that causes the `unexpected EOF` error which here is the `if` section and put the else section in the `catch` section. it looks like this:

```
def isDone = false
def response = ""
def state = ""
sh "mkdir -p ${workspace}/results/${currentBuildNumber}/$testCaseName"
for (int i = 0; i < 10 && isDone == false; i++) {
  sh "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i $testCaseName | awk '{ printf (\$4 == \"Running\") ? \"yes\" : \"'wait'\" }' > ${workspace}/results/${currentBuildNumber}/$testCaseName/commandResult.txt"
  sh "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i $testCaseName | awk '{ printf \$4 }' > ${workspace}/results/${currentBuildNumber}/$testCaseName/podState.txt"
  timeout(time:30,unit:"SECONDS") {
    waitUntil {
      response = readFile "${workspace}/results/${currentBuildNumber}/$testCaseName/commandResult.txt"
      return (response != "")
    }
  }
  timeout(time:30,unit:"SECONDS") {
    waitUntil {
      state = readFile "${workspace}/results/${currentBuildNumber}/$testCaseName/podState.txt"
      return (state != "")
    }
  }
  try {
    if ("$response" == "yes") {
      println("$testCaseName pod is running")
      isDone = true
    } else {
      println("$testCaseName pod state is: $state")
      sleep(time:1,unit:"MINUTES")
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    println("$testCaseName pod state is: $state")
    if ((i == 9) && (isDone == true)) {
      error("Build failed because $testCaseName pod couldn't start")
    } else {
      sleep(time:1,unit:"MINUTES")
    }
  }
}
```